# Freemarker servlet error: The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, servlets, freemarker

When trying to reach "hostname:8080/WebTest1/users" I get this error below:

```
HTTP Status 404 -
type Status report
message
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

My web.xml looks thusly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WebTest1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <!-- Added these for the freemarker templates to work with the servlet -->
    <servlet-name>freemarker</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet</servlet-class>

    <!-- FreemarkerServlet settings: -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>TemplatePath</param-name>
        <param-value>/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>NoCache</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ContentType</param-name>
        <param-value>text/html; charset=UTF-8</param-value>
        <!-- Forces UTF-8 output encoding! -->
    </init-param>

    <!-- FreeMarker settings: -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>template_update_delay</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
        <!-- 0 is for development only! Use higher value otherwise. -->
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>default_encoding</param-name>
        <!-- <param-value>ISO-8859-1</param-value> -->
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        <!-- The encoding of the template files. -->
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>number_format</param-name>
        <param-value>0.##########</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>freemarker</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ftl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello_servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.fivetech.freemarker.examples.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>user_servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.fivetech.webtest1.servlets.UserServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello_servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello-ftl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>user_servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/users</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!--
    Prevent the visiting of MVC Views from outside the servlet container.
    RequestDispatcher.forward/include should and will still work. Removing
    this may open security holes!
-->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>FreeMarker MVC Views</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.ftl</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <!-- Nobody is allowed to visit these -->
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

My bean User.java looks like:

```
package com.fivetech.webtest1.models;

public class User {

public String firstname;
public String lastname;
public String username;
public String password;

public User(String firstname, String lastname, String username, String password) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return this.firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return this.lastname;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}
}
```

The Servlet class (UserServlet.java) looks like:

```
package com.fivetech.webtest1.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/users.ftl").forward(request, response);

}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //nothing here yet
}

}
```

I have a 404 from this but I'm sure I am missing something small but I haven't been able to figure it out yet. Any ideas?

Comment: I might add the hello-ftl (HelloServlet) works fine with no issues.

Comment: Are there any startup errors?

Comment: Hi SD, I get these:

    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows   optimal performance in production environments was not found on the  java.library.path:  /Users/fivetech/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Netw ork/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
    Sep 05, 2013 10:41:42 AM     org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context}    Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:WebTest1' did   not find a matching property.